# Android provide push Notification badge count?

Tags: push-notification

I am stating to implement push notifications in my app in android and have a question about the badge count. I would like my app to behave like email and other apps, such that every time an alert is received the badge count number increments.

Any clarification on this would be most helpful.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't have badge style notification.
Once notification received from GCM then modified ur code to show badge notification on app icon.
All the manufactures are not supporting, samsung, sony and HTC supports to show badge notification.

In android, we don't have badge style approach as iOS but some manufactures are supporting to display badge on app icons.

[Example for badge style icon on app in android](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/07/android-ios-style-badge-app-icon-for.html)